# What is the difference between running JUnit tests with "Run As" and Maven's test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven, m2e, jmockit

I have some problems I don't understand exactly. I have some class called ApplicationContext which extends android.app.Application. This class will be mocked by JMockIt's `MockUp<T>`. When I let my JUnit tests run by `mvn install`, everything works well, but when I run my tests with `Run As->JUnit Test` I get exceptions like this (only with this one test which extends android.app.Application)...

```
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type [unknown] not present
```

I guess that this has something to do with the fact that android must be in provided scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>${platform.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Maybe the tests don't have this package at runtime or something. But I wonder why they just have it at `mvn install`, since the package is always linked as Maven dependency. I need to understand why classes from android.app.Application are not found when I run test with "Run As". Here are some of my configuration settings:

[image: Build path]

**.classpath**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**.project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>net.devgems.android.kurzparkzonewien-TRUNK</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.devgems.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>kurzparkzonewien</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>kurzparkzonewien</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>1.6_r2</platform.version>
        <android.sdk.path>/opt/android-sdk-linux</android.sdk.path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>0.999.17</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>bin/classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>bin/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>4</platform>
                        <path>${android.sdk.path}</path>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you need more additional information, please tell me, because I'm not sure where to isolate the problem properly.

Comment: The complete Eclipse build path would be valuable additional information. Screenshot or contents of the `.classpath` file. And why not the `.project` file.

Comment: Can you post the complete pom.xml?

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, you are missing <dependency> android-test in pom.xml, see example [here](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/blob/master/morseflash/morseflash-instrumentation/pom.xml).

Comment: Unfortuantely that doesn't help. I'm not sure if I really need it, because when I add it as dependency, I don't see any more Maven dependencies. But this is obviously the proper Maven behaviour for this dependency because adding and deleting other dependencies work as expected.

Comment: By the way, it is unused when I test it with dependency plugin:  
`[WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    com.google.android:android-test:jar:1.6_r2:provided
[WARNING]    com.google.android:support-v4:jar:r6:compile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that the error explained in my question is the proper behavior. This is so because you must not expect from an Eclipse project that Eclipse (or the ADT plugin) knows how to deal with dependencies organized by Maven. This is a Maven project, so Maven must be used to install, deploy and test. I think the difference between "Run As" and "mvn test" is, that the first uses the Eclipse's built in JUnit libraries located in plugins directory, the latter uses the libraries configured by Maven. So these are two different worlds and they have nothing in common. In my opinion it's just coincidence that a Maven project mostly works with Eclipse Run As and so on. But if there are dependency issues, Eclipse cannot manage it, since it is a Maven project and not an Eclipse project.

But for this case above I found a nice workaround which works at least for testing. I have to go to "Java Build Path -> Libraries" and I had to add all Maven dependencies including the used android.jar as external dependency (it doesn't affect Maven).  Then I was able to execute all tests by "Run As -> JUnit Test" (whereby sometimes I have to execute "Project Clean" at first, because otherwise I run into ClassNotFoundExceptions).

If I'm wrong with my assumptions, feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main difference is:

`Run as Maven test` will ONLY test classes that end with *"Test"* are executed.
If the test classes end for example with "Tests" or with anything else they are not executed.
But `Run as JUnit Test` will test ALL test cases in ALL Classes.

Detailed differences are listed in the below URL:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/UIMA/Differences+between+Running+Unit+Tests+in+Eclipse+and+in+Maven

Comment: i think in maven the tests will also be executed if they a prefixed by Test , no ?

Comment: ALL test methods which annotated by @Test inside `test classes which ended by Test word` will be executed by maven regardless of its name, the condition only applied on Classes name, not Methods names

Comment: i tried with a class which name starts with "Test"  but didn't ended with "Test" , like TestApp1 , and it was executed by maven

Comment: @AmarBessalah try `mvn clean install`, and you will see that test cases inside `TestApp1.java` will not be triggered